# Getting the Box of a Button

Tags: front-end, notebooks, button

I have a useful snippet of code that I use for anything in my notebook that takes a while to execute and doesn't need to be executed for subsequent cells:

```
buttonEvaluate[expr_] := Module[{cell}, 
   Button["Evaluate", 
     cell = Cell[BoxData[ToBoxes[ expr ]], "Output"];
     SelectionMove[ButtonNotebook[], All, ButtonCell]; 
     NotebookWrite[ButtonNotebook[], cell]
     ,
     Method -> "Queued"
   ]
];

SetAttributes[buttonEvaluate, HoldFirst];

buttonEvaluate::usage = "Returns a button, that when pressed, replaces itself with the evaluation of the passed in expression. Useful for things you don't necessarily care to recalculate when the notebook is evaluated.";
```

I usually use it like this:

```
some[expression,that,takes] + a * long / time // buttonEvaluate
```

...and when that cell is executed, the output is a button labelled `Evaluate`, which, when pressed, replaces the output cell with the result. This means I can use `Evaluation->Evaluate Notebook`, and it effectively skips over some cells until I explicitly choose to evaluate them.

However, I've run into an issue when I try to use it inside an expression, because the perfectionist in me wants to be able to do something like:

```
Row[{slowThing[] // buttonEvaluate, fastThing[]}]
```

However, the `Button's` action is to replace the `ButtonCell` with the results, which inadvertently replaces everything, not just the `Button's` Box. So, two questions:

1. Is there any way to select the `Box` of the `Button`?
2. Will replacing that selection using `NotebookWrite` work how I want it to? I can imagine it might play havoc with *Mathematica's* formatting.

Comment: I'd love to be able to work with something like inline cell's tags as with ordinary tags.

Comment: @Widjet, I guess, you need to change the settings of a `SelectionMove` because it selects All output cell with button inside instead of a just button.

Comment: Does my answer fit your needs?

Comment: @Kuba It does indeed, thank you. 'tis a clever solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### V10 edit

As of V10 it is easier to do that with a help of `EvaluationBox[]`. Your second concern is solved by temporarily changing `DefaultDuplicateCellStyle`. [**78417**](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/78417/5478)

```
ButtonHold ~ SetAttributes ~ HoldFirst;

ButtonHold[expr_] := Button[
   Tooltip["Evaluate", HoldForm[expr]]
   ,
   Module[{nb = EvaluationNotebook[], pre, opt = DefaultDuplicateCellStyle},
     pre = Options[nb, opt];
     SetOptions[nb, opt -> "Output"];
     NotebookWrite[EvaluationBox[], ToBoxes @ expr];
     SetOptions[nb, pre]
   ]
   ,
   Method -> "Queued"
];

Grid[{{1, Button[1]}, {ButtonHold[Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 1}]], 
  4}, {ButtonHold[Plot[Cos[x], {x, 0, 1}]], 10}}]
```

[image]

---

#### Old solution

Not pretty but works. The trick is to inject `Unique` string to the box so it can be found later in whatever you wish to have in that cell.

Cell expression with replaced `BouttonBox` is then overwritting button's parent cell.

```
buttonEvaluate2 = Function[expr,
   
   Button["Evaluate", 
          #;
          SelectionMove[EvaluationCell[], All, Cell]; 
          NotebookWrite[ EvaluationNotebook[],
                         NotebookRead[EvaluationCell[]
                              ] /. b_ButtonBox /; MemberQ[b, #, {3}] :> ToBoxes@expr
                         ];
          , Method -> "Queued"
         ] &[ ToString @ Unique["x"] ]
   ,
   HoldFirst];
```

---

#### test

```
Grid[{
  {1, Button[1]},
  {buttonEvaluate2[Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 1}]], 4},
  {buttonEvaluate2[Plot[Cos[x], {x, 0, 1}]], 10}
  }]
```