# NotebookWrite in EvaluationBox forces Input CellStyle

Tags: functions, front-end, notebooks, boxes

There is a promissing new function `EvaluationBox[]` and a nice last example in documentation section for it:

```
Button["date", NotebookWrite[EvaluationBox[], ToBoxes @ DateString[]]]
```

> [image]

(*Click*)

> [image]

The problem is that this string is in an **"Input" cell** now! Why was it converted?

Quite a problem because it is not easy to [change cell style](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/24777/5478).

---

I was trying:

```
Button["date",  NotebookWrite[EvaluationBox[], 
   Cell[#, "Output"] & @ BoxData @ ToBoxes @ DateString[]]]
```

but the problem remains. On the other hand we can see that it is not a problem of `NotebookWrite` itself but of `EvaluationBox[]` because `EvaluationCell` replaced by the code above gives correct output:

```
Button["date", NotebookWrite[EvaluationCell[], 
  Cell[#, "Output"] & @ BoxData @ ToBoxes @ DateString[]]]
```

---

Any thougts?
Quick work arounds?

I've introduced one, ugly but working here: [Getting the Box of a Button](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/70253/5478) . I was trying to improve it with `EvluationBox[]` but the I've faced this issue.

Comment: Kuba, I have edited "walkaround" in your posts to "work around" several times in the past, but I think you should make the edit this time to help you learn the correct English idiom.

Comment: @m_goldberg Sorry and thank you. I should be more focused on English, not only the issue.

Comment: I don't see how this can be fixed by a work around. `EvaluationBox` is going to create a cell no matter what, and you don't want a cell. If you did, sacratus' answer would serve you. But because you want a box structure to insert into a possibly much larger expression, I think `EvaluationBox` is simply inappropriate for the purpose you have in mind. Therefore, I would not call what you have encountered a bug.

Comment: @m_goldberg Box is supposed to be part of Cell so I don't see how one can expect that replacing EvaluationBox may influence whole cell. Or have I missed something?

Comment: It looks to me that you have missed that any use of `EvaluationBox` has the side effect of deleting the output cell containing the button and then creating a new cell in your notebook.

Comment: @m_goldberg I'd have missed this if it was stated somewhere. Now, it makes not sense :( `"EvaluationBox[] 
returns a BoxObject corresponding to the box structure in which this function is being evaluated."`

Comment: The documentation for `EvaluationBox` is very poor and looks to be hastily written. I think you have a good case for complaining to WRI about the documentation.

Comment: @m_goldberg on my way! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `NotebookWrite` in this manner is really no different from manually modifying the content of an Output cell.

The FrontEnd converts the cell to Input, since it anticipates the user would be interested in evaluating it afterwards.

What style is used is determined by `DefaultDuplicateCellStyle`.

Comment: If it is so, ok, I can undestand motivation. However lack of description in NotebookWrite page or no link around to DefaultDuplicateCellStyle even in Low Level Notebook Programming guide are enough to defend my angry attitude. What do you think?

Comment: I am not certain I would expect the behavior of the editor to be documented in a function page.  It would kinda imply that the behavior is specific to calling the function, which is obviously not true.  However, it is completely reasonable suggestion to document this behavior in a more discoverable fashion.

Comment: You've got the point but those things are related, and Possible Issues section or See also seem like appriopriate places.

Answer (score 1):

I have a possible work around here:

```
Button["date", 
NotebookWrite[EvaluationCell[], 
Cell[#, "Output"] &@BoxData@ToBoxes@DateString[]]; 
SelectionMove[EvaluationNotebook[], Previous, Cell]; 
CurrentValue[Cells[NotebookSelection[EvaluationNotebook[]]][[1]], 
StyleNames] = "Subsection"]
```

unforunately i could not test `EvaluationBox[]` because i have only Mathematica 9 available here. I used `EvaluationCell` instead and changed the style of the cell to "Subsection" for demonstation. Use "Output" instead if it works for `EvaluationBox`.

Comment: It has the problem described in http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/24777/5478

Comment: @Kuba Strange, can one make a bugreport on this? The idea with `CurrentValue` is from the documentation of `Cells`! Ugly that it messes up the CellStyles. I'll have another look on this...

Comment: @Kuba reported, but no workaround at the moment. hope they will fix it!

Comment: Yes i reported CurrentValue with CellStyle and used the example from the documentation to show the problem.

Comment: Great, keep us informed :)

Comment: Ok, instead of `CurrentValue` you can use this [answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/78443/5478)

Comment: @Kuba i got an answer from WRI, they say its not a bug: (*"In this case, Mathematica is behaving as designed. In particular, the StyleNames item does not apply to the cells you are looking at. Further, StyleNames is an undocumented symbol, meaning that it's usage can change without warning. In this particular case, however, if you simply ask for the current value of StyleNames for a given cell, you get back an empty list. Please see the attached notebook for details."*)